# Asking the user to re-enter year of birth until birth year < current year

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I have a problem that how to keep show a prompt until user enter their birth year is always smaller than the current year. Here is my code I try using loop but now  i struggle. I hope someone can help me, I appreciate it.

```
<body>
<p id= "age"></p>
<button onclick=" notify()">Try it</button>
<script>
function notify(){
let age = prompt("Your birth year");
        const year = new Date().getFullYear();
        do {
          document.getElementById("age").innerHTML =
            age + " is a good year";
        } while (age < year && age != null);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion:

```html
<body>
  <p id="age"></p>
  <button onclick="notify()">Try it</button>
  <script>
    age_p = document.getElementById("age");
    function notify() {
      let age = prompt("Your birth yeat");
      const year = new Date().getFullYear();
      if (parseInt(age) < year) {
        age_p.innerHTML = age + " is a good year";
      } else {
        notify();
      }
    }
  </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. the test for "if age greater or equal to current year continue looping" appear to be around the wrong way. Try `>=` instead of `<` as the age/year comparison operator.
2. Make sure to call `prompt` again if the year entered is unacceptable.

Show the snippet to see a working version:

```js
function notify(){
        let age;
        const year = new Date().getFullYear();
        do {
          age = prompt("Your birth year");
        } while (age >= year && age != null);
        document.getElementById("age").innerHTML =
            age + " is a good year";
}
```

```html
<p id= "age"></p>
<button onclick=" notify()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: You too man, you are awsome

Answer (score 0):

**This suggested solution reworks your code considerably to try to improve both UX and maintainability.**

- A `prompt` modal dialog is easy for us to set up but tends to be [clunky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#notes) for the user. (An [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) element, in this case a numeric one, is usually the best way to get user input.)
- Inline event handlers violate [SoC](https://www.newtarget.com/web-insights-blog/separation-of-concerns-in-web-design-and-development/) while being less flexible than **[proper event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

(There are stylistic changes here, too, but these are just personal preference and can be safely ignored.)

**(See the in-code comments for further clarifications.)**

```js
// Gets current year, and identifies some DOM elements
const
  year = new Date().getFullYear(),
  yearInput = document.getElementById("year-input"),
  outputParagraph = document.getElementById("output-paragraph"),
  submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");

// Calls notify whenever button is clicked
submitButton.addEventListener("click", notify);

// Alternative listener setup you could try -- makes button unnecessary
// yearInput.addEventListener("change", notify);



// Chooses and shows message (by comparing inputted year to current year)
function notify(){

  const userYear = yearInput.value;
  let message;

  if(userYear === "")     { message = ""; }
  else if(userYear > year){ message = "Greetings, time traveller"; }
  else                    { message = "You are fit for your age"; }

  outputParagraph.textContent = message;
}
```

```css
input{ width: 8ch; }
```

```html
<label>
    Your birth year
    <input id="year-input" type="number" />
</label>
<button id="submit-button">SUBMIT</button>
<p id="output-paragraph"></p>
```